# Sybase isql : An error occurred when attempting to allocate localization-related structures

Tags: visual-studio-code, batch-file, cmd, sybase, isql

When executing `isql` in VSCode, I see this error:

```
The context allocation routine failed when it tried to load localization files!!
One or more following problems may caused the failure
 Your sybase home directory is C:\SAP. Check the environment variable SYBASE if it is not the one you want!
Using locale name "en_US.UTF-8" defined in environment variable LANG
Locale name "en_US.UTF-8" doesn't exist in your C:\SAP\locales\locales.dat file
An error occurred when attempting to allocate localization-related structures.
```

It works fine when executing directly from cmd.exe. Only when I run it inside a bat file did it produce the error.

Home directory and `locales.dat` file are both fine, LANG is currently set at `en_US.UTF-8`.

Has anybody encountered the same issue?

I cant use admin right BTW.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages indicate that some environment variables have not been loaded.

While the installer updated your Windows environment variables such that you have no issues when running `isql` from `cmd.exe`, I'm guessing the `.bat` file is unable to access the Windows environment variables (I'm really rusty with Windows `.bat` behavior so that's just a guess at this point).

In a linux/unix environment all scripts and programs need to first load the Sybase-specific environment variables, and this is performed by sourcing the `$SYBASE/SYBASE.sh` file.

In a Windows `.bat` script you should be able to load the Sybase-specific environment variables by running the `%SYBASE%\SYBASE.bat` file (where in your environment it appears `%SYBASE% == C:\SAP`)